# Proc reg qq-plot output data

Tags: sas

I would like to get the data behind the qq-plot generated by the proc reg in SAS. So that I could draw the plot myself (with some additional information)

```
proc reg data=sashelp.cars;
    model invoice = horsepower weight;
    plot residual.*nqq.;
run;
```

[qq plot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/damvw.png)

I was trying to check the ods outputs, but non of them seems to have it.
Or is there an easy way to calculate the numbers myself from any of the outputs?

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2012/08/01/data-fro-ods-graphics.html

Comment: @Reeza That should be an answer, not a comment :)

Comment: @Joe Links aren't considered answers and I'm too lazy to type it out ;)

Comment: @Reeza Thanks! Perfect solution, i spent already a half day trying to find it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
ods graphics on;
proc reg data=sashelp.cars  plots=QQPlot;
    model invoice = horsepower weight ;
    plot residual.*nqq.;
    ods output QQPlot = QQData;
run;
```

blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2012/08/01/data-fro-ods-graphics.h‌​tml